# Concatenation within Doctrine 1 query, unknown relation alias

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine, symfony1

I've run into an issue with (I believe) concatenation within a Doctrine 1 query. The query has been tested in Phpmyadmin and confirmed to return the desired results, however when run as `Doctrine_Query::create()` I'm getting an `Unknown relation alias` error in my php log.

The query:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->select('id')
      ->from('TableName')
      ->innerJoin('OtherTable')
      ->where('TableName.table_column LIKE CONCAT("%[",OtherTable.id,"]%")')
      ->andWhere('OtherTable.id='.$EXTERNAL_VAR)
      ->andWhere('TableName.other_table_column=value');
```

The error (written to an external log file):

```
[Tue Dec 09 11:28:25 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Unknown relation alias , referer: http://local.environment/
```

I've isolated the problem to be the above query, but aren't sure how to reformat the CONCAT line to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your innerjoin. Doctrine doesn't understand how to join the tables. (thus the message *"Unknown relation alias"*)

Is the relation specified in your schema file ?
If you just defined this relation or done other changes to the schema file have you done a rebuild of the model ? (with **symfony doctrine:build-model**)